# Using cert file for SSL authentication in Java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am writing a simple java program to call a RESTful web service and I have been provided with a `.cer` file for SSL authentication.

I am not sure how to use a `.cer` file in java for SSL Handshake, because of which I get a `SSL Handshake error` when I try to call the web service.

Could you please guide me here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I have been provided with a .cer file for SSL authentication.

That's not sufficient.

You should have a private key, and you should have created it yourself, not been given it, and you should have generated either a self-signed certificate from it or else a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) and had the CSR signed by a certificate authority (CA).

To use this to authenticate yourself in Java, both the private key and the certificate need to be in a keystore under the same alias, and you need to provide the keystore and its password via the system properties `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword`, or else via a more complicated code method which you will find documented in the JSSE Reference Guide.

Comment: Yes I used the below command to generate JKS from .cer file: "keytool -importcert -file "exxon-devca-client.cer" -keystore exxon-devca-client.jks -alias "exxon-devca-client""
Also added below lines to my jeresy rest client code:
File resourcesDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/exxon-devca-client.jks");
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", resourcesDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");

But now I get below error:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

Comment: I can only repeat. You should have *started* with a private key, and for that you have to start with a JKS file. There's no question of generating a new JKS file from a .cer file. You have to import it into the same keystore you generated the CSR from, using the same alias. NB Please don't post computer commands or output or code in comments. You can see for yourself it's completely illegible.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable handshake. Here is test code:

```
    private static void sslTest(String serviceUrl, String username, String password) throws Exception {
       System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");

       CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
       provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

       SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
               .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {

                   @Override
                   public boolean isTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {
                       return true;
                   }
               })
               .useTLS()
               .build();

       SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
       CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

       String content = "";


       try {
           HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(serviceUrl));
           if (Integer.toString(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()).equalsIgnoreCase("200")) {
               HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
               content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
               System.out.println(content);
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           logger.error("Exception : {}", e.getMessage());
       }
   }
```

Comment: This insecure code does not disable the TLS handshake. It disables checking the certificate that is received during the handshake. Doesn't answer the question and not safe to use.

Comment: mine is a jeresy rest client, the above code won't work.